# Send as shared mailbox alias

Tags: exchange-2010

In Exchange 2010 I have a shared mailbox with two emailaddresses (alias). How do I sent an email using one of the aliases? I'm already using smartreply and choosefrom for my own mailbox, but it doesn't seem to work with shared mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd have to do it programmatically.  Otherwise, it will use whatever is the primary SMTP address for that shared mailbox by default.

You can do it via Outlook though. Open the shared mailbox as an additional mailbox, give yourself full access and send as permissions, and then change the from Address by typing in the actual SMTP alias you want to send as after clicking the `From` option.  The 2nd field should have the "Send from" option set to the shared mailbox you have open.

Comment: When I add the mailbox as an additional mailbox, it does not show up in the From address field. When I type in the actual SMTP alias, the shared mailbox is not shown in the 2nd field. The user has Send as rights on the shared mailbox, but when she tries to send an email using the alias, it returns an error that the user is not allowed to send mail